# saving setting into database

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE siteConfig (
    settingName     VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    value           VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (settingName)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

display these setting.
settingdisplay.php

```
$setting = siteConfig::find_all();

    $this_page = array(
                        'recaptcha_public_key','recaptcha_private_key','spam_register','spam_login',
                        'spam_register_emp','spam_login_emp','spam_apply','spam_contact','spam_share',
                        'spam_feedback','spam_forgot','spam_rsc'
                       );

    foreach ( $setting as $s )
    {
        if( in_array($s->settingName, $this_page) )
        {
            $_SESSION['set_ses'][ $s->settingName ] = isset($_SESSION['set_ses'][ $s->settingName ]) ? $_SESSION['set_ses'][ $s->settingName ] : $s->value;
        }
    }
```

part of html which is displaying these setting.

```
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>{lang mkey='label' skey='spam_register'}</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="txt_setting[spam_register]" id="spam_register" class="checkboxField" {if $smarty.session.set_ses.spam_register == 1 } checked="checked"{/if} /></td>
</tr>
```

once all the information is change then this page save it to database.
Update.php

```
foreach( $_POST['txt_setting'] as $k => $v )
    {
        $setting->settingName   = $k;
        $setting->value     = $v;

        if( $setting->updateSiteConfig() )
            $k = true;
    }
```

When I check the box my update.php see nothing.

I dont know how to get 1 or 0 value from these checkbox.

Fixed.................

```
$yes_or_no_key=array(list of my keys);
if( in_array($k, $yes_or_no_key) )
        {
            $setting->value = $_POST['txt_setting'][$k] == 'on' ? 1 : 0;
        }
```

This fixed my problem. Thank you for your qick response.

Comment: value of checkboxs are sent **ONLY** if they're checked!

Comment: I have check the checkbox's but they is nothing is coming the other side. I like to get 1 or 0 from checkbox.

Comment: sorry its only the part which is display this check box.I havn't put full html code as they is lot.

Comment: you have to put `value="1"` or something like that, so when check box is checked, it has a value, otherwise, it will be empty!

Comment: i did add this but it was not packing anything up.

Comment: I have create a array list of all the yes or no answer keys, if they matches the key then I try doing this. $setting->value = $_POST['txt_setting'][$k] == 'on' ? 1 : 0;

Comment: now,check them using a foreach and Pierpaolo's answer. if you didn't understand what I', saying, tell me to put the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> value of checkboxs are sent ONLY if they're checked! – Death

So you need something like this:

```
if (!isset($_POST['txt_setting[spam_register]']) $_POST['txt_setting[spam_register]'] = 0; // 0 value
```

Comment: I can do this with sinlge value $_POST['txt_setting[spam_register]'] == 'on' ? 1 : 0;

Answer (score 0):

If you need the values to be One or Zero for a particular option, I would suggest the use of radio.

```
<input type="radio" name="txt_setting[spam_register]" id="spam_register" class="checkboxField" value="0" {if $smarty.session.set_ses.spam_register == 1 } checked="checked"{/if} />    
<input type="radio" name="txt_setting[spam_register]" id="spam_register" class="checkboxField" value="1" {if $smarty.session.set_ses.spam_register == 1 } checked="checked"{/if} />
```

Also, remember to set the value in the forms so that you can access them using $_POST or $_GET in PHP.

Comment: Oh, checkbox will only pass data if it's being checked. So if you checked the checkbox holding the value 1. Then you will only get the data one. Remember to put in the value inside the form.

Comment: I have lot of settings and I like to use checkbox for 1 and 0 values.so for e.g. If checkbox is checked then the value is 1 if its unchecked then value is 0